# ValueConverter for Unchecked CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to load an item when the CheckBox is selected and if it is selected it should disappear because something else will be loaded.

Where did I make a mistake in this case?

XAML:

```
    <StackPanel> 
      <StackPanel.Resources>
        <vm:NegatingConverter x:Key="NegatingConverter"/> 
      </StackPanel.Resources>

        <CheckBox Content="Load?" Name="LoadsDifferent"/>

        <StackPanel Height="15" Width="360" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=LoadsDifferent, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource NegatingConverter}}">
           <TextBlock>Load line<Run BaselineAlignment="Subscript" FontSize="10">k</Run> [kN/m]</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

NegatingConverter

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(bool))]
    public class NegatingConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !((bool)value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're returning a boolean when it expects a visibility, you need a boolean to visibility converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding a `bool` value to the `Visibility`, which will cause the binding to fail. As the default value of `Visibility` is `Visible`, you will see no change.

Here is a `NegatedBooleanToVisibilityConverter` that you may find useful:

```
public class NegatedBooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var flag = false;

        if (value is bool)
        {
            flag = !(bool)value;
        }

        if (parameter != null)
        {
            return flag ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        return flag ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works properly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per my review, for UI level operations, you should always prefer Xaml scripting to improve performance. There is no need to implement converters when you have powerful triggers in WPF.

your request can be achieved using triggers easily as mentioned below.

```
  <StackPanel>

        <CheckBox Content="Load?" Name="LoadsDifferent"/>

        <StackPanel Height="15" Width="360" >
            <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=LoadsDifferent, Path=IsChecked}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=LoadsDifferent, Path=IsChecked}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>
            <TextBlock>Load line<Run BaselineAlignment="Subscript" FontSize="10">k</Run> [kN/m]</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```